# PHP, regexp and parsing game logs

Tags: php, regex, parsing

```
INFO_MAP name:"mapname" version:"1.2.3"
INFO_SETTINGS mode:"Mode_Normal" options:"Option_None"
PLAYER_CONNECT player:0 name:"testname" id:1231231 psr:1000.00
PLAYER_TEAM_CHANGE player:0 team:2
ITEM_PURCHASE time:0 x:13906 y:13485 z:110 player:2 team:2 item:"Item_ItemName" cost:250
ABILITY_UPGRADE time:0 x:13906 y:13485 z:110 player:2 team:2 name:"Ability_Example1" level:1 slot:2
ITEM_PURCHASE time:0 x:13869 y:13740 z:110 player:1 team:2 item:"Item_AnotherItem" cost:100
PLAYER_CHAT player:3 target:"team" msg:"Test Message with Spaces"
```

I have this style gamelogs which I have to parse via PHP. Which is the most efficient way to get something useful out of these, current strstr+explodes system is really terrible, coded by prior developer(s). I am thinking of regexp but unable to get anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

A regex like this should work:

```
^([^\s]+)(\s+([^:]+):("[^"]+"|[^\s]+))+
```

Changed a bit for PHP (works for me with PHP version 5.1.6):

```
<?php
$pattern = '/([^\s]+)?(\s+([^:]+):("[^"]+"|[^\s]+))/';
$file_handle = fopen("logfile", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
   print_r($matches);
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: It only grabs the mode + last arg/val combo.

Comment: I suppose in PHP you will have to use a preg_match_all and use this regex:
`([^\s]+)?(\s+([^:]+):("[^"]+"|[^\s]+))`

Answer (score 0):

I would work trough the log line by line, getting the first action using `substr` and then process the rest using a function using `explode` or a `preg_match_all`. If this is exactly what the other programmers did, I think they did a good job.

Perhaps I wouldn't use regular expression at all, as it's  inefficient when you have *really* large logfiles.

Comment: if(strstr($log_line, 'PLAYER_CONNECT'))
 {
  $line = explode(" ", $log_line);
  $id = explode(":", $line[1]);
  $name = explode(":", $line[2]);

Comment: Problem with explode(" ", $line) is that PLAYER_CHAT player:3 target:"team" msg:"Test Message with Spaces" <-- msg: part explodes too many times